# Modx with custome API (adding new wsdl file)

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

I'm new to modx and before I go further in it I would like to know if we can add a new WSDL file so that we can use remote soap or rest APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use the MODX api through soap or rest, or do you mean to integrate a soap/rest API in a ModX site? There are no obstacles to the later!

Answer (score 0):

You should read about Modx one more time. What it is, what it does (and doesn't).

Modx is a great framework/cms that supports pure PHP-snippets. In these snippets you can write any PHP and output anything you like. Using PHP's SOAP-library should be no problem what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Optimus & Kristian.

Kristian : I got a remote system that got loin information that got a API's. So is it possible to use the WDSL file of this system on MODX to use it to login and to pull other data (with a soap API).